# How to create circular Slider WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

I was wondering how to create a scroll that looks something similar to this:

[image]

I'm really interested on being able to build one like this, and I'm not sure on what elemnt is this one and how to implement it. I've been searching, but I can't find any information... So any tutorial, guide or clue will be really appreciated.

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at "[A Knob Slider Control](http://alala666888.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/a-knob-slider-control/)". It doesn't look as nice as your example, but that's just a matter of styling.  Maybe you could use it as a starting point?

Comment: Hummm yes, that one looks more what I'm looking for... Thanks! Good starting point, yep :)

Answer (score 2):

See the [tutorial](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/08/Curved-ScrollBars.html) of Charles Petzold. It gives a nice introduction how to create curved sliders and scrollbars.

Comment: I've seen it before, but I'm not sure if that will be enough. thanks!