# How to create a Curve slider in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a curve slider for WP8. Can anyone suggest from where to begin with.

Comment: add a snapshot regarding what do you want to do with question.

Comment: Show what have you tried..

Answer (score 2):

[Radial Slider for Windows Phone](https://github.com/HankiDesign/Windows-Phone-Radial-Slider) => You need to add `Microsoft.Expression.Drawing` assembly.

[How to create circular Slider WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397498/how-to-create-circular-slider-wpf)

[A Modern UI radial gauge control for Windows Phone 8 apps](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/11/05/A-Modern-UI-radial-gauge-control-for-Windows-Phone-8-apps.aspx)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I can't add the code, the code is huge. SO answer has 30000 characters limit.

Comment: It needs 30.000 character to create a slider?

Comment: Yeah, why don't you check it. I am not lying.

Comment: I don't say that you lying. It was only surprising to me, but I'm not so involved in WP8 that I would say you were a liar. If the links help Clerissa - all fine. But from **my** point of view this is more a comment than a answer. Nothing personal against you.

Comment: Yes I also prefer to post the code, but I am not able to post so posted only link.

Comment: The curve is semicircle. If ellipse is being used I cannot eliminate the lower half of the circle.

Comment: Check out updated answer. You have to replace ellipse with arc. All solution will require some manipulations from your side.

Comment: I had already tried Modern UI Ragial Guage. And I have succeeded in getting a semicircle and a Thumb on top of it. However in Modern UI Radial Guage they are using a slider to change the value. I did not understand how to bind the slider to the Thumb. Hence looking for a different solution.

Comment: I had even replaced the ellipse with arc. The code is as below:

Comment: I had even replaced the ellipse with arc. The code is as below:<es:Arc StartAngle=-90 EndAngle=90/> If we observe closely the lower arc is present.(If we reduce the arc height,the arc height is distorted)