# Circular Slider in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I really want to create circular slider. I've been searching, but I can't find any information. So any tutorial, guide or if someone already created like this. Please post their XML code.

[image]

Comment: Why would you want a circular slider - it would be completely unintuitive to use

Comment: To make the user Interface better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create circular Slider WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397498/how-to-create-circular-slider-wpf)

Comment: @auburg, subjective much?

Comment: @auburg it was also completely unintuitive to think of cars getting curvy when people drove in flat boxy cars back in 80s.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making a circular slider (which as @auburg points out) *would* be a little unintutive to use (think the old telephone dials), consider making it a dial like a thermostat:

[image]

It's functionally very similar, but has a much larger hit-test area and is therefore less easy to mess-up for the user.

Try this guide: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2012/12/06/walkthrough-building-a-sweet-dial-in-xaml-for-windows-8/

Answer (score 1):

A circular slider can be implemented just like a normal horizontal or vertical slider. The only difference would be that in the MouseMove event handler of the thumb during the drag operation you cannot just handle the horizontal or vertical position. Instead you have to calculate the angle relative to the center of the slider and map that to the value of the slider.