# How to drag the black dot to change the value of the progress bar, just like Slider？

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

How to drag the black dot to change the value of the progress bar, just like Slider.

Now I can make the black point change with the progress value, but I don't know how to drag the black point to change the value.

How to do the drag and drop of this black spot?

What is the idea? Which methods should I use?

style:

```
<Style x:Key="circularProgressBar1" TargetType="local:CircularProgressBar">
            <Setter Property="Value" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="7"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CircularProgressBar">


                        <Canvas Width="100" Height="130">
                            <Ellipse Width="105" Height="104" Margin="-2.4,-1.5,0,0" Stroke="LightGray" Opacity="0.7"  StrokeThickness="8"  />


                           
                            <Path Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}"  StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
                              StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding StrokeThickness}">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <PathGeometry>
                                        <PathFigure x:Name="fig" StartPoint="20,90">
                                            <ArcSegment RotationAngle="0" SweepDirection="Clockwise" 
                                                    Size="50,50"
                                                    Point="{Binding Path=Angle, Converter={StaticResource prConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ProgressBar}}"
                                                    IsLargeArc="{Binding Path=Angle, Converter={StaticResource isLargeConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ProgressBar}}"
                                                    >
                                            </ArcSegment>
                                        </PathFigure>
                                    </PathGeometry>
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                            <Button>
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate>
                                                    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="10" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round">
                                                        <Path.Data>
                                                            <PathGeometry>
                                                                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                                                                    <PathFigure StartPoint="{Binding Path=Angle, Converter={StaticResource prConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ProgressBar}}">
                                                                        <PathFigure.Segments>
                                                                            <LineSegment Point="{Binding Path=Angle, Converter={StaticResource prConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ProgressBar}}" />
                                                                        </PathFigure.Segments>
                                                                    </PathFigure>
                                                                </PathGeometry.Figures>
                                                            </PathGeometry>
                                                        </Path.Data>
                                                    </Path>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>
                        


                            <Border Width="100" Height="100">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50"   Fill="White"  />
                                    <Image Width="20" Height="20" Margin="30,25,30,30" Source="bulb1.PNG"/>

                                    <TextBlock Width="50" Foreground="Black" Height="20"  Margin="10,40,10,5" TextAlignment="Center"
                                   Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0}%,  
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                       FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"/>
                                </Grid>

                            </Border>
                            <Canvas  Canvas.Top="110">
                                <Button x:Name="decrease"  Margin="20,0,0,0" Command="{Binding DecreaseCommand}" >
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                                        <Grid>
                                                            <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="LightGray"  StrokeThickness="1"  />
                                                            <Border Width="20" Height="20" >
                                                                <TextBlock Foreground="LightGray" Text="-" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                            </Border>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Style>
                                </Button>
                                <Button x:Name="increase"  Margin="60,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding IncreaseCommand}" >
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                                        <Grid>
                                                            <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="LightGray"  StrokeThickness="1" />
                                                            <Border Width="20" Height="20"   Grid.Column="1">
                                                                <TextBlock Foreground="LightGray" Text="+" FontWeight="Bold"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

                                                            </Border>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Style>
                                </Button>
                                <!--<Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="LightGray"  StrokeThickness="1"  Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                                    <Border Width="20" Height="20" Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="LightGray" Text="-" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </Border>
                                    <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="LightGray"  StrokeThickness="1"  Margin="60,0,0,0"/>
                                    <Border Width="20" Height="20" Margin="60,0,0,0">
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="LightGray" Text="+" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

                                    </Border>-->

                            </Canvas>
                        </Canvas>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Xaml:

```
 <Grid Background="DarkBlue">
        <local:CircularProgressBar Background="White" Style="{StaticResource  circularProgressBar1 }"
                                      Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Value="{Binding  Value}"   BorderBrush="LightGray" />
  
       

        <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="100" 
                    x:Name="CirularSlider" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Value="{Binding  Value}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Codebedhind:

```
    public class CircularProgressBar : ProgressBar
        {
            public CircularProgressBar()
            {
                this.ValueChanged += CircularProgressBar_ValueChanged;
            }
    
            void CircularProgressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
            {
                CircularProgressBar bar = sender as CircularProgressBar;
                double currentAngle = bar.Angle;
                double targetAngle = e.NewValue / bar.Maximum * 359.999;
              //  double targetAngle = e.NewValue / bar.Maximum * 179.999;
    
                DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(currentAngle, targetAngle, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
                bar.BeginAnimation(CircularProgressBar.AngleProperty, anim, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace);
            }
    
            public double Angle
            {
                get { return (double)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
                set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
            }
    
            // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Angle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
            public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
    
            public double StrokeThickness
            {
                get { return (double)GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty); }
                set { SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
            }
    
            // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StrokeThickness.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
            public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeThickness", typeof(double), typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(10.0));
        }
    
       public class AngleToPointConverter : IValueConverter
    {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double angle = (double)value;
        double radius = 50;
        double piang = (angle - 143.2) * Math.PI / 180;
        //double piang = angle * Math.PI / 310;

        double px = Math.Sin(piang) * radius + radius;
        double py = -Math.Cos(piang) * radius + radius;

        return new System.Windows.Point(px, py);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
    
        public class AngleToIsLargeConverter : IValueConverter
        {
    
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                double angle = (double)value;
    
               return angle > 180;
               // return angle > 300;
            }
    
            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: if you want to drag and adjust it you should probably base your control on the sloider and not on the progressbar

Comment: you would have to calculate the path between mouse and center of the circle and then see at which angle this line  hits the center and translate it to a progress 0° = 0% 360% = 100% on the mouse move event of the progressbar

Comment: Just choose an appropriate drag behavior, for example ignore the movement along the progress track and only follow vertical mouse move (up and down). Mouse down on the thumb marks the current start value of your progress. Now define a mouse move to progress ratio e.g. 1:1 one pixel adds 1/-1 to the value of the progress bar.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39099238/9007184) The linked video tutorial is something I definitly gotta try.